# Function getting called without click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everytime I run this code , witjout clicking the 2 divs , the function doSomething and doSomething2 get called. Can somebody explain the reason please.

http://jsfiddle.net/JuKmM/5/

```
function doSomething2(){
 console.log("div 1 clicked");
}

//var element1=document.getElementById('div_1');
//var element2=document.getElementById('div_2');
//element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething2,false);
//element2.addEventListener('click',doSomething,true);

$("#div_1").click(doSomething2());
$("#div_2").click(doSomething());
function doSomething(){
console.log("div2 clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `function` instead of passing its `reference`.

Try this,

```
$("#div_1").click(doSomething2);
$("#div_2").click(doSomething);
```

Fiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JuKmM/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the function by appending `()` at the end. To the `click()` method you need to pass the handler function references as given below

```
$("#div_1").click(doSomething2);
$("#div_2").click(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this instead:

```
$("#div_1").click(doSomething2);
$("#div_2").click(doSomething);
```

`$(...).click(doSomething)` means "call the function `doSomething` when a click event happens in the future"

`$(...).click(doSomething())` means "call the function `doSomething` now, then use its return value as the action to take when a click event happens in the future."